# Add more spacing between different files in git diff

Tags: git, config, diff

I have a large git repo with many files and frequently need to review many changes. When I do `git diff`, I just get a wall of text that is very difficult to read because the diff of each file is just concatenated. Although there is a git header before every file's diff, it just blends into the content in my terminal, and it's too hard to quickly scan through a long diff and identify specific files.

How can I make git diff add some whitespace between each file when producing the diff? Solution can be CLI, TUI or GUI (but I use Debian Linux).

Comment: Since the output is pager-ized, and `less` has search-with-highlight, I just do `/^commit` and then hit `n` to go to each next file when eyeballing big diffs like this.

Comment: Would [this](https://github.com/so-fancy/diff-so-fancy) help you?

Comment: @GoodDeeds Yes!